# auth_info in janrain authentication

Tags: android, authentication, janrain

I am trying to use janrain to handle authentication fir many providers in my Android app. After a successful provider login I get the auth_info data from janrain.

I am trying to understand the details in it but I can't find anything in the documentation. Specifically I am interested in the **"device_token"** and the **"token"** variables.

Providing excerpts from two providers:

Google+ provider:

{device_token=fb95763f605f13f8d71cd5d18ec9a5275xxxxxx, token=04c858ede0e14035a4d17c3ccab987b91xxxxxx, stat=ok, profile={providerSpecifier=googleplus, googleUserId=xxxxxxxx
.
.
.
}

Facebook provider:

{device_token=986e9c441cfec5093f608a5c7a672981cxxxxxx, token=748b628d2e82d593fdc271793e9672c9axxxxxx, stat=ok, profile={providerSpecifier=facebook, providerName=Facebook
.
.
.
}

Can anyone explain why I need the two tokens?

Answer (score 0):

**"device_token"** is for Social Sharing.

**"token"** is a one-time use token that is used with the auth_info endpoint.

So if you don't have Social Sharing, then you wouldn't really need to use the "device_token".

Here is the Janrain Mobile SDK repo, as well as documentation: https://github.com/janrain/jump.android/blob/master/Docs/Jump_Integration_Guide.md